# Searching on MultiValue Managed properties

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, multiple-values

In SharePoint 2013 we have created 3 managed properties with multi values as follows:

```
Name    Type    Multi   Query   Search  Retreive    Refine  Sort    Safe Mapped Crawled Property

Amounts Double Precision Float  yes yes yes yes yes no  Yes 
Dates   Date and Time           yes yes yes yes yes no  Yes -
Persons String                  yes yes yes yes yes no  Yes -
```

NOTE: we have tried to set the search flag to no as well, but the behavior is the same.

We have created a Content Enrichment Service that populates this Managed properties. Every document can have 0 to many values for each of this properties.

The implemented solution works fine. The Managed Properties are filled by Content Enrichment Service, and all of the Managed Properties can be used as refinements on a Refinements Web Part.

However, the search is not functional for the DateTime and Douuble Managed Properties.

Entering query like this :

```
http://localhost/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=(Persons:%22someone%22)
```

returns expected results, but doing query like this:

```
http://localhost/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=Amounts%3E150
```

or

```
http://localhost/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=Dates%3E%3D01.01.2013
```

results with the
„We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure you're using the proper syntax.“
Response page.

We are using the correct syntax for date-time and Double query, because running such queries on Managed Properties of the same data type but that accepts only a single value results with a proper search results.
Can you assist us how to configure the managed properties, so that they accept multiple values and we can use them in refinements and in search.

Any help is most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved in two SharePoint public updates released by Microsoft.

March Public Update for SharePoint 2013 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36989

August Public Update for SharePoint 2013
http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2013/08/14/august-2013-cu-forsharepoint-2013-has-been-released.aspx